# Batch File To Get It's Own Directory Or The Directory Defined In The "Start In" Property Of A Shortcut

Tags: batch-file, target, shortcut, working-directory, startup-folder

I am writing a batch file on my Windows 8.1 machine. In one section of my batch file I need to start a command prompt in the "current working directory".

So far, this is what my batch file looks like:

```
@echo OFF
set WORKING=%cwd%
start cmd.exe /K pushd %WORKING%
exit
```

Let's say the batch file is located in the folder *C:\Temp\Utilities*.  If I open an explorer window and double click the batch file to run it everything works great. A new command prompt is created in the directory *C:\Temp\Utilities*. However, if I right-click the batch file and select *Run as administrator* the working directory is no longer the location of the batch file, it's *C:\Windows\System32*.

Similarly, if I create a shortcut to the batch file in a different folder (for example. C:\Temp) and repeat the two steps above the results are the same. If I double click the shortcut and run it as a normal user the working directory is what I would expect. (Note, the working directory for the shortcut it's whatever is set for "Start in" of the shortcut properties, not the location of the batch file.) If I right click the shortcut and run it as administrator I again get a command prompt opened to the folder *C:\Windows\System32*.

I assume this is a "bug" or "feature" (if you want to call it that) in Windows 8.1 and it probably happens because execution environments for programs run as administrator are forced to run in the *System32* folder? (I remember with Windows 7 this did not happen so it must be a new *feature* to Windows 8.)

I found one way to fix the issue and stop the command prompt from starting in *C:\Windows\System32*. I did this by modifying the following line in the batch file:

```
set WORKING=%~dp0
```

Doing it this way sets the working directory to the location of the batch file. With this change, no matter how I run the batch file or the shortcut (administrator or normal) the working directory ends up being the same, *C:\Temp\Utilities*.

The problem with this solution is I don't want the working directory to always be the location of the batch file. If the batch file is run directly then it's okay but if I run it from a shortcut I need the working directory to be whatever is set in the "Start in" property of that shortcut. For example, if the batch file is located in the folder *D:\Temp\Utilities* this is what I need to happen regardless of whether I run as administrator or not:

```
Shortcut Location    Start In Property    Command Prompt Working Directory
--------------------    -------------------     ------------------------------------------
C:\Temp                  <undefined>           D:\Temp\Utilities
C:\Data\bin             C:\Data\bin             C:\Data\bin
C:\Data\bin             D:\Temp\Utilities     D:\Temp\Utilities
```

What this means is I can't always use *%~dp0* to set the working directory in my batch file. What I need is some way for the batch file to know if it was run either directly or by a shortcut. If the batch file is run directly then the working directory is easy to get, it's just the value of *%cwd%*. If the batch file is run by using a shortcut, I don't know how to get the "Start in" property inside the batch file.

Does anyone know how I can do these two things inside my batch file:

*1. Check whether it was run directly or by a shortcut.*

*2. If run by a shortcut, get the "Start in" property of the shortcut that started it.*

Thank you,

Orangu

*UPDATE*

I found sort-of a "hackish" way to fix the issue. For the shortcut I edited the "Target" field and changed it to the following:

```
cmd.exe /k pushd "C:\Temp" && "D:\Temp\Utilities\batchfile.bat"
```

Now the working directory can be obtained by calling *%CD%* in the batch file and this works for both administrator and normal users. It does not, however, work for the case when I run the batch file directly. I still need to use *%~dp0* in that case.

I don't like this solution, however, because it requires me to manually change all shortcuts I make and it also makes the icon look like a cmd prompt icon rather than a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered to not use shortcuts at all?

You could e.g. create a `batchfile_exec.bat` containing your call

```
REM optionally do 
REM cd /D working_directory
REM if you want to force a special working directory
D:\Temp\Utilities\batchfile.bat
```

and replace all the shortcuts with `batchfile_exec.bat`. If you double-click `batchfile_exec.bat`, the working directory will be the one containing `batchfile_exec.bat`.

I personally don't like Windows shortcuts that much, because they are hard to handle within a revision control system. As you also noticed, it is very time consuming if you want to modify a lot of them.

By the way: If `batchfile.bat` was designed/written to be always run from the direcory where it is located, you might also consider to modify `batchfile.bat` to force that behaviour:

```
setlocal
cd /D %0\..

REM your original content

endlocal
```

In `%0` the path to the batchfile is stored.

The trick is to assume that `%0` is a directory and then to change one level lower based on that directory. With `/D` also the drive letter is changed correctly.

The `cd` command doesn't care if `%0` is really a directory. In fact `%d` doesn't even have to exist (`%0\dummy\..\..` would also work).

The `setlocal` command is to have the working directory being restored when `batchfile.bat` has finished (this would be good if `batchfile.bat` was called form another batch file).

I noticed that the `endlocal` command is not really necessary in this context since it is applied implicitly when `batchfile.bat` finishes.